# Html Card text expand

Tags: html

i have cards tha fetch data from database , Can you give me a solution how to manage that sample of text, i don't want too much lines, i want if it possible to have 2 lines and when i click on the text then open something like modal to show all the text

[image: Example]

is it possible with to make something with simple way? without js?

```
 <div class="flex space-x-2 text-gray-400 text-sm my-3">
                            <!-- svg  -->
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                stroke="currentColor">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2}
                                    d="M7 8h10M7 12h4m1 8l-4-4H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-3l-4 4z" />

                            </svg>
                            <div class="flex  overflow-y-auto    space-x-2 text-gray-400 text-sm my-3">
                                <p class="text-left ">{{ $service->comments }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: overflow-y:hidden with constant height maybe, but JS is more elegant and would give you much more control...

Comment: Yes I tried something like this, can you give me an example with js?